# Changing a setting for TinyMCE in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tinymce

I have this line:

```
'paste_remove_spans': True,
```

that I want to use to stop TineMCE from automatically adding `<span>`'s to text that is pasted into the editor.

I know how to change the layout/buttons of the editor for wordpress like so:

```
function change_mce_options( $init ) {
 $init['theme_advanced_blockformats'] = 'p,address,pre,code,h3,h4,h5,h6';
 $init['theme_advanced_disable'] = 'forecolor';
 return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'change_mce_options');
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to add this new rule. Do I need to make a filter for that aswell?

Comment: You should just have to add a line to your function: `$init['paste_remove_spans'] = true;` to achive this.

Comment: @KristerAndersson I tried this but it still adds additional `<span>` tags to the text that I'm pasting into the editor.

Comment: That seems very strang, have you tried disabling/re-enabling your theme, I'm think that this might be a cache issue.

Comment: @KristerAndersson This worked. It has now stopped adding in random `<span>`'s. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have to modify your code to this:

```
function change_mce_options( $init ) {
  $init['theme_advanced_blockformats'] = 'p,address,pre,code,h3,h4,h5,h6';
  $init['theme_advanced_disable'] = 'forecolor';
  $init['paste_remove_spans'] = true;
  return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'change_mce_options');
```

Also, make sure so your cache is cleared by disabling/re-enabling your theme or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working anymore...

But I've found out solution that works:

change tinyMCEPreInit variable : for example, when I want to show just H3 and <p>:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit.post_editor.block_formats = "Paragraph=p;Heading 3=h3";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where did you put this Javascript?

Comment: there are many options, you can put it in footer, or enqueue as script file, or put it inline somewhere in specific template